# Problemas para coger la configuración

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, archivo, microservices

Me he creado un servicio de configuración por el cual quiero que otros servicios cojan la configuración (puerto, constantes etc).

Mi servicio de configuración tiene las siguientes propiedades:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Logró levantar y funciona correctamente, levantado en el puerto: 8888, pero cuando levanto el otro micro servicio (MicroUno)
[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouQD9.png)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me levanta en el puerto 1234, sino en el 8080 (el que coge por defecto), es decir que no esta cogiendo la configuración del servicio anterior a pesar de que esta levantado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

enter image description here

¿Qué me falta por añadir para que realmente funcione?

Que me coja las propiedades de mi fichero de configuración.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. El código, los mensajes de error y configuraciones debes copiarlas y pegarlas como texto en la pregunta y no como imágenes. Haz clic en [edit] y cambia todo lo que haga falta, de lo contrario tu pregunta podría terminar cerrada. Saludos

Comment: a mi tb me ocurre pero no he sido capaz de saber nunca porque